# why does it do this when initializing a 2d list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

when I initialize an array in python like so and then assign an element to a different value and then print out the 2d list

```
dist = [[0]*3]*3
dist[1][1] = 1
```

It gives me this

```
[[0,1,0],[0,1,0],[0,1,0]]
```

Can someone explain to me why the whole column has changed instead of just the specific element?

Comment: dist is a list of references to a list containing 3 zeros. Try `[[0]*3 for i in range(3)]`

Comment: You are not using arrays, you are using nested lists.

Answer (score -1):

Because each of your 3 columns are references to the same object.

If you had created `dist` like so:

```
dist = [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
```

you would see the behavior you expect.